# MobileFirst Adapter: JSON result order is different as that of the DB data position

Tags: mysql, json, adapter, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I have created a `logintable` with Username and Password as its column.
I have configured the adapter in `MobilFirst environment`. When invoking the adapter I got the below output:

```
Invocation Result of procedure: 'procedure1' from the MobileFirst Server: 
{
   "isSuccessful": true,
   "resultSet": [
  {
     "pwd": "Harry123",
     "usrname": "Harry"
  }
 ]
}
```

But in my DB UserName comes first and then Password.

My DB structure:

> usrname varchar(20)
>
> pwd varchar(20)

Could you please let me know why the order or position of the data varies in Invocation Result.

Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that the response looks like this

```
var result = { "resultSet": [
  {"pwd": "Harry123", "usrname": "Harry", "age": 2 },
  {"pwd": "wibble", "usrname": "Dave", "age": 64 },
  { "usrname": "Tarsim", "pwd": "2020", "age": 27 }
  // many more records here
]};
```

And we are interested in the data for "Dave". We could iterate through the result set looking for Dave:

```
 var rs = result.resultSet;
 for ( i = 0; i < rs.length; i++) {   
        if ( rs[i].usrname == "Dave ) {
            // do something with rs[i]
        } 
 }
```

I often find that I want quick access to records by some field, such as usrname, so I create a map - remember JavaScript objects can be treated as associative arrays:

```
var rsMap = {};
var i;
for ( i = 0; i < rs.length; i++) {   
     rsMap[rs[i].usrname] = rs[i];
     }
```

Now we can simpley refer to rsMap[anyUsrName], for example Dave's pwd:

```
rsMap["Dave"].pwd;
```

or Tarsim's age:

```
var name = "Tarsim";
rsMap[name].age
```

or work with Harry's record:

```
var name = "Harry";
var record = rsMap[name];
```

Answer (score 2):

Adapters convert the response to JSON and send it back to the client.

JSON is [unordered](http://json.org/).
Which means that in your response {a:1,b:2} is absolutely the same as {b:2,a:1}.

This is the expected way for the response to be.

Comment: Further, it surely makes no difference to your code, you will access the columns by name for example:  resultSet[x].usrName

Comment: Hi Idan, 
Thank you so much for your quick turn around!
Is there any possibility to change the order? If suppose we are fetching 100 data from the table and JSON displays it in a different order. how could I recognize which row is represented by which JSON object dynamically in code? i.e How could I store and retrieve it using a result set if the order varies (without looking into JSON)?

Comment: As djna wrote, the order does not matter because you do not retrieve by order but by property name.

Comment: To clarify, JSON maps are unordered.  JSON arrays ARE ordered.  In your single record above, it is somewhat difficult to tell your original input data, but assuming you had multiple records, they would be processed into the resultSet Array in the order provided.  The map fields within each record are unordered, and this is fine.  Such that you could safely iterate over the resultSet array in the normaltive order.

`for( var i=0; i<rs.length; i++ ) { console.log("Item", i, " : ", rs[i].usrname); }`